# Unban command | discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

I recently made a discord unban command for my bot:

This is my code so far:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Client, Message, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
  name: 'unban',
  description: 'unban',
  aliases: ['unban'],
  execute: async (client, message, args) => {

        if(!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) {
          return message.channel.send(`**${message.author.username}, you do not have perms to unban someone.**`)
        }
        
        if(!message.guild.me.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) {
          return message.channel.send(`**${messageg.author.username}, I do not have perms to unban someone.**`)
        }

  
        let userID = args[0]
          message.guild.fetchBans().then(bans=> {
          if(bans.size == 0) return 
          let bUser = bans.find(b => b.user.id == userID)
          if(!bUser) return
          message.guild.members.unban(bUser.user)
    })
        
      ;}}`
```

I want the bot to send a message when they unbanned the member. I already tried many methods but none of them worked, so I ask here!

I also want the bot to send a message if the user sent a wrong id.

(***Note***: The bot command works!)

Comment: Simply adding `message.channel.send(\`I have successfully unbanned ${bUser.user.tag}.\`)` after `message.guild.members.unban(bUser.user)` should work.

Comment: Yup no problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
message.guilds.members.unban(bUser.user).then(() => {
message.channel.send('Success!')
})
```

This sends message after you have unbanned.